# How to find the variance of $X_1-\bar{X}$ for iid $X$'s

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid as $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. I'm trying to find the Variance of $X_1-\bar{X}$. Here's what I have:

\begin{align}
 Var(X_1-\bar{X})&=Var(X_1)+Var(\bar{X})-2Cov(X_1,\bar{X}) \\
  &= \sigma^2+\frac{\sigma^2}{n}-2[E(X_1\bar{X})-E(X_1)E(\bar{X})] \\
&= \sigma^2+\frac{\sigma^2}{n}-2[E(X_1\bar{X})-\mu^2]
\end{align}

The $E(X_1\bar{X})$ is throwing me off here, as I'm pretty sure $X_1$ is not independent of $\bar{X}$. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$EX_i\overline {X}=\frac  1 n EX_i \sum_j X_j=\frac  1 n \sum_j EX_iX_j$. Note that $EX_iX_j=EX_i^{2}=\mu^{2}+\sigma ^{2}$ if $i=j$ and  $EX_iX_j=\mu^{2}$ if $i \neq j$.

Comment: Great, thanks! So then the sum would be $n\mu^2+\sigma^2$.